# What motor do i use to rotate a tumbler at low RPM and high torque which run by a battery charged by solar?

Tags: motor, ac, solar-cell, mechanical, rpm

I am gonna run the motor to turn a tumbler of 50-85 kg @ 5 rpm MAX.

The motor will be powered by a battery which will be charged by solar.

So should i go for a DC or AC motor? Single phase or 3 phase? Which is the best for long term use? This motor will run only for 5 mins a day everyday. I was thinking to use 1-1.5 hp and place it like shown in the picture with a pulley and belt.

Suggest me other alternatives also.

Problem: 
What motor should I get so that the speed of the large tumbler is 5 RPM?
Or do I get a motor and just fix a gear box? [image]

Comment: Before you choose a motor and gearbox, why not calculate the energy you need to rotate the drum, then continue from there.

Comment: what is energy? like torque? or volts? or watts? I am a finance student i am kind of a noob in this.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you need far less than 1-1.5 Hp. You need to calculate or measure how much power is required rather than guess. To measure, attach a spring scale, (luggage or fish scale) to the perimeter of the drum and determine the required torque.

You will need a gear to reduce the drive speed to a reasonable speed for the small pulley. You can probably find online recommendations for the minimum size for the small pulley.

A DC motor with brushes will probably be the least expensive alternative. Depending on the power required, it could be simply turned on and off with a relay. If more than a few hundred watts is required you will probably need an electronic speed control (ESC) to limit the motor current during starting. In that case, a brushless DC motor and ESC may be a more attractive alternative. If you really do need 1 to 1.5 Hp, a three phase AC motor and a variable frequency drive might be attractive, but that would require higher voltage than may be convenient to supply from the solar panel system.

Comment: Will the ac motor heat up if it's rated rpm is 2500 and I reduce it to 25 rpm? But only for like 5 mins.

Comment: 2500 RPM is not possible for a normal AC motor connected to mains power. You could reduce the speed a motor rated a 2500 RPM down to 5 RPM, but would only have 1% of rated power. If 25 RPM is the highest speed you ever need is makes no sense to select a 2500 RPM motor.

Comment: so i how i maintain a high torque at low speed could you suggest me the type of a motor?

Comment: With a good ESC, any type of electronically controlled motor can provide 100% of full-speed torque all the way to zero speed or nearly zero speed. However power = torque X speed; so power is reduced proportionally as speed is reduced. That means that a 1 Hp motor will only provide 0.1 Hp at 10% of rated speed and 0.01 Hp at 1% of rated speed. If you never operate at rated speed, you are buying a motor that is much larger than necessary. That is why gears are used to match the motor to the load. Also, at low speeds, a separately powered fan may be needed to cool the motor.